# Escape variable in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a piece of code:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do (
    echo echo %%A ^>^>myfile.txt>>myfile.bat
)
```

As some of you can see, this code reads myfile.txt, and creates myfile.bat, which when opened creates an exact copy of the original myfile.txt. The problem comes in when myfile.txt contains special characters, such as >. **How can I escape the %%A variable?**

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Processing each line requires escaping, why not append the file to a small stub which split's the `payload` and deletes itself afterwards?

Comment: No, i can't. This is just a small part of a bigger program.

Comment: You double each percent symbol to escape them. `echo echo %%%%A ^>^>myfile.txt>>myfile.bat`

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46134196/edit) your question and post some contents of your `myfile.txt` and expalin more your aim ?

Comment: @Hackoo the test content is: test >> Hello

Comment: @Squashman I want to escape the contents of the variable, not the name of the variable

Comment: @PieterMantel Please check my answer !

Answer (score 0):

I have this idea : using `Certutil` command to encode your text file and generate it again like this batch script can do :

```bat
@echo off
set "MyTxtFile=myfile.txt"
for %%i in (%MyTxtFile%) do (
    set "MyBatchFile=%%~ni.bat"
    set "TempFile=%%~ni.B64"
    Set "NewFile=%%~ni__%%~xi"
)

@for /f %%i in ("certutil.exe") do if not exist "%%~$path:i" (
  echo CertUtil.exe not found.
  pause
  exit /b
)

Rem to encode your text file to a temporary file
Certutil -encode "%MyTxtFile%" "%TempFile%" >nul 2>&1

(
    echo @echo off 
    echo Title Generate code of "%MyTxtFile%" to "%NewFile%"
    echo CERTUTIL -f -decode "%%~f0" "%NewFile%" ^>nul 2^>^&1 
    echo Exit
)> "%MyBatchFile%"

@Copy "%MyBatchFile%" /b + "%TempFile%" /b >nul 2>&1
Del "%TempFile%" >nul 2>&1
Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak>nul & exit
```

***EDIT***

This code can generate what you want based on your last comment `test >> Hello` :

```bat
@echo off 
Title Generate code of "myfile.txt" to "myfile__.txt"
CERTUTIL -f -decode "%~f0" "myfile__.txt" >nul 2>&1 
Exit
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
dGVzdCA+PiBIZWxsbw0KDQo=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: No, for the program I need the echo ^>^> >> myfile.txt format

Answer (score 0):

The following *commented* code snippet could help (see [Variable Edit/Replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem silently create empty output files - just for testing
>NUL COPY /Y NUL myfile46134196.bat
>NUL COPY /Y NUL myfile46134196ou.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile46134196in.txt) do (
    set "_aux=%%A"
    rem replace every `Greater Than` symbol with a properly escaped one
    echo echo !_aux:^>=^^^>! ^>^>myfile46134196ou.txt>>myfile46134196.bat
    rem             ^>       properly escape `Greater Than` symbol - input string
    rem                  ^>                                        -output string
    rem                ^^    add a caret (Circumflex Accent) to output string
)

rem debugging outputs
echo ON
type myfile46134196.bat
@ECHO OFF
rem test: run currently created .bat file
call myfile46134196.bat
rem test:                                 and show result
echo ON
type myfile46134196in.txt
type myfile46134196ou.txt
@ECHO OFF
```

**Output**:

```
==> .\so\46134196.bat

==> type myfile46134196.bat
echo test^>^>hello >>myfile46134196ou.txt

==> type myfile46134196in.txt
test>>hello

==> type myfile46134196ou.txt
test>>hello

==>
```

**Further resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%A` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`^` caret)  [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)